# How to debug NestJS webpack HMR in VSCode

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, webpack, nestjs

I am trying to debug NestJS application that has webpack HMR setup descibed in [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload)

Here my VSCode `launch.json` file

```
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "node",
      "restart": true,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
      "skipFiles": [
        // Ignore node_modules folder when debugging.
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        // Ignore NodeJS when debugging.
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
      ],
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/**.js"],
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
    }
```

here the `webpack-hmt.config.json`

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({
        name: options.output.filename,
        nodeArgs: ['--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229'],
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Unfortunetly, when I run debugger and set a breakpoint in my controllers they don't get hit.

Comment: Wondering if you ever made progress or found a solution to this one...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just got rid of HMR. Actually, there is no need to use it. Without it I woucld easily make debugger work, if you need further help ping me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/612

To summarize, in the `webpack-hmr.config.js`, add `devtool: "inline-source-map"`, and add `nodeArgs: ["--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"]` to the properties passed to `RunScriptWebpackPlugin`.

The entire `webpack-hmr.config.js` is:

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require("run-script-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    entry: ["webpack/hot/poll?100", options.entry],
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ["webpack/hot/poll?100"],
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({
        name: options.output.filename,
        autoRestart: false,
        nodeArgs: ["--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"],
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Then launch with this launch configuration:

```
    {
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "start:dev"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node"
    }
```